# Distribution of $\dfrac{X_{i}}{\max X_{i}}$?

Tags: normal-distribution, extreme-value

Suppose we have a sample of standard normal i.i.d. observations $X_{1}, X_{2}, \cdots ,X_{n}$, what can we say about the asymptotic distribution of $V_{i}$ and $W_{i}$, where:
$V_{i}=\dfrac{X_{i}}{\max X_{i}}$ and $ W_{i}=X_{i}-\max X_{i}$?

Comment: $V$ is going to be weirder  than $W$, especially for small $n$, though both will have points of positive probability $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @Henry, Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm interested in the asymptotic distribution.

Comment: I'm confused .. are you missing a subscript i on the V and W?

Comment: If the support of $X$ is unbounded above, then does this simply collapse to $0$ as $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\operatorname{Max}(\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\})} = 0$?

Comment: @Igor, indeed, I corrected it.

Comment: @MatthewGunn: Possibly, but simulation suggests $\sqrt{E[V_i^2]}$ is still over $\frac14$ when $n=10^4$

Comment: Maybe this will help you a little: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89030/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-gaussian-random-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case where there is a fixed maximum and you record any $X_i$ below that maximum then the distribution of $X_i$ will follow a [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution).

Of course your case is a bit more complicated, your maximum depends on the values of $X_i$.

Let $\phi(z)$ be the pdf of the standard normal distribution and $\Phi(z)$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution. Also let $Y=max(X_i)$.

In order to get a maximum of $y$ from $n$ samples you need one sample to be equal to $y$ and the others must be less than or equal to $y$. This is like a binomial distribution; there are $n$ samples which could be equal to $y$ with a pdf of $\phi(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma})$ and the remaining $n-1$ samples which are less than $y$ with a probability of $\Phi(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma})^{n-1}$. Therefore the distribution of the maximum is:

$$f(y)= n\ \phi \left(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\ \Phi \left(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{n-1}$$

Clearly the distribution of $W_i$ will have one value equal to $0$ and the rest are negative. You are interested in the negative values.

As mentioned before $W$ will have a truncated normal distribution with a constant subtracted from it. However, the upper limit to the truncated normal is now a random variable with distribution $f(y)$.

For a given maximum $y$ the distribution of $w$ is:

$g(w)=\frac {\phi ({\frac {w-\mu+y }{\sigma }})}{\Phi ({\frac {y-\mu }{\sigma }})}$    for $w\leq 0$

Considering that $y$ is a random variable we can integrate over all possible $y$ to get the distribution of $w$

$g(w)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\phi ({\frac {w+y-\mu }{\sigma }})}{\Phi ({\frac {y-\mu }{\sigma }})} n\ \phi \left(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\ \Phi \left(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{n-1} dy$ $\ \ \ $   for $w\leq 0$

Perhaps from this you can determine the asymptotic distribution of $W$ and apply a similar approach to the distribution of $V$

Comment: Initially I had $W_{i}=X_{i}- a$, where $a$ is a constant, then I noticed that $a$ is the max of the $X_{i}$s, so for any record of $X$ the maximum depends on the length of the sample not the observations.

Comment: @ToneyShields I'm not sure what you're saying. I can't spot how "observations" means anything different to "samples".

Comment: What I meant is that $a$ (the maximum) is a function of the sample size not a fuction of the $X_{i}$s.